# How to deploy nodejs application on linode port 80?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, deployment, linode

I am using Linode instance (Ubuntu 20) to deploy my website.

Running the nginx server with default return `IP_ADDRESS` to the default nginx page and `IP_ADDRESS:3000` to my actual application (when ofcourse it's running).

I want to allow the user to access my application directly using just IP_ADDRESS/
Now, for this I modified two things-

1. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` - Changed default to root `/root/APP_NAME/`
2. `/etc/nginx/nginx.cong` - changed user from www-data to root

Now, what this does is serve my app.js file in `plain text` rather than actually serving the application irrespective of whether or not I have started my application using `node app.js` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the default to root /root/APP_NAME. When you do that, NginX will serve files in your NodeJS app folder as static files.

What you need is to configure NginX to forward the request coming at port 80, to the NodeJS application.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

This tutorial explains step by step: https://hackernoon.com/configure-nginx-s-a-reverse-proxy-for-your-nodejs-application-9tk032e8